# unexpected keyword argument 'raise_on_status'

Tags: python, pip, quandl

I installed quandl using pip. 
I imported it and tried it:

```
import quandl
mydata = quandl.get("FRED/GDP")
print(df.head())
```

This resulted in the error below. 
Any suggestions how to solve it?

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-a47ca7d841f3> in <module>()
      1 import quandl
      2 #df = quandl.get("SSE/SVHG")
----> 3 mydata = quandl.get("FRED/GDP")
      4 #mydata = quandl.get("DATABASE_CODE2/DATASET_CODE2")
      5 print(df.head())
......


~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/quandl/connection.py in get_retries(cls)
     72                         status_forcelist=ApiConfig.retry_status_codes,
     73                         backoff_factor=ApiConfig.retry_backoff_factor,
---> 74                         raise_on_status=False)
     75 
     76         return retries

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'raise_on_status'
```

Answer (score 0):

The error appeared during [instantiating of Retry](https://github.com/quandl/quandl-python/blob/33149816637b239db6a6436cc3d4a2d5a60d5fe4/quandl/connection.py#L69) and said `Retry` is [a class from urllib3](https://github.com/quandl/quandl-python/blob/33149816637b239db6a6436cc3d4a2d5a60d5fe4/quandl/connection.py#L4).

There is `raise_on_status` in `urllib3` in [the repository](https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/blob/0cedb3b0f1e5d79c89c6db767c534b064b794cf2/src/urllib3/util/retry.py#L130). Perhaps you have an older version of `urllib3` and need to upgrade it.

Comment: Thanks! The following made it work: 
pip3 install urllib3 --upgrade --user

Answer (score 0):

`cd ~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/quandl/` and Open `connection.py`. 
Go to line 74 and remove the argument `raise_on_status`
Worked for me!!